# Excel add-in does not load automatically to my excel test file when running in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, excel-addins, office-addins, office-js

When I use the "new workbook" option as the start document, the add-in loads automatically but when i add my own test file it doesn't load. I have to go to manually start it in the insert tab.

How do i fix it?

Comment: is it a VSTO add-in ? And what do you mean by test file ?

Comment: No. It's the new java script add-in. They used to call them office apps In Office 2013. And the test file is a file that has some sample data for the add-in to work on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

Simply click save in Excel after loading the app from the insert menu.